# Customizing Images in Wix Installer in a customized dialog

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

I have created a setup of a project using wix installer ,which was created in vs2010.Now i have completely created the setup for the project.But i need to replace the images in the wix installer with my product image.

i have used

```
    <UIRef Id="MyWixUI_InstallDir" />
```

and have customized the dialog's.I have used this lines to refer for the images,

```
   <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Banner.bmp" />
   <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Dialog.bmp" />
```

bit was not working .but if i give reference to the default (ie) this `<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />` insteasd of `<UIRef Id="MyWixUI_InstallDir" />` ,then the images are correctly working. But i need the same to be done in my customized dialog.

Thanks in Advance.
Arshad.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following in your custom dialog:

```
<Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
```

i.e. `!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)` as reference. That should do the trick, at least it works for me.

The same works for the Dialog-bitmap:

```
<Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.WelcomeDlgBitmap)" />
```

Comment: Actually am new to wix.I need to assign my logo even in the first dialog (ie) Installer starting dialog , How to assign it ??  @taffit